# Can "vetted" be used to mean somebody to whom some restrictions are not applied?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Using a CMS, I found the following description for a user setting.

> If checked, this user will be granted "vetted" status. Vetted users create full projects and promote existing experimental sandboxes.

*Vetted users* is used to refer to users who can create full projects and sandbox projects; non-vetted users are only allowed to create sandbox projects.

Is it correct to use *vetted* in this case?
If it is correct, what is the meaning of *vetted*, in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Vet" here is being used with [this meaning](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vet):

"to appraise, verify, or check for accuracy, authenticity, validity, etc.: *An expert vetted the manuscript before publication.*"

So a "vetted" user is one who's been checked out (by the project manager or whoever) and can therefore be given expanded permissions.